# 0 questions and 0 answers on profile?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page

I sometimes look at profiles , but occasionally i see something remarkable.
Example : 0 questions 0 answers 0 votes 0 views 0 badges reputation 395.

Where did that 395 come from then ? 
Are the questions hidden ? Profile changed ? IT trick ?

Weird.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the example?  Were you looking at a profile on meta.math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: If you previously belong to other stackexchange sites, then you get some bonus points when you join math.stackexchange .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least two possibilities:

1. Account association with an account on another SE site that itself has earned 200 rep, gives a one-time bonus of 100 rep.
2. A suggested edit to a question or answer, which is later approved by a user with 2000+ rep will earn the suggester 2 rep. This possibility goes away once the user reaches 2000 rep -- auto-approved edits are worth nothing.

So a user with no questions or answers but 395 rep probably has the initial 1 rep, a 100 rep association bonus, and 147 accepted edit suggestions. (Or no bonus and 197 edits).

Comment: Don't you need 1000 reputation, or something like that, to be able to do the edits?

Comment: I know for sure that users with 101 rep can suggest edits. I think _all_ registered users can, and also unregistered users under some additional conditions.